# How to redirect to a particular page in a Webview when when a push notification is received

Tags: ios, xcode, redirect, uiwebview, push-notification

I have a `UIWebView` in my ViewController. I need to redirect it to a particular page when a push notification is received, The method to receive push notification is in `AppDelegate`.
So how can i access that `UIWebView` which is in ViewController from `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nsnotification observers

when ever a push notification received you can post a notification like below

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushNotificationReceived" object:nil];
```

and in the controller class you can observer the notification and do what ever you want.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadWebview:) name:@"PushNotificationReceived" object:nil];
```

this is one of the way.